# angular14 create component inside iframe

Tags: angular, typescript, iframe, appendchild

I'm building an angular 14 application which has the ability to let the user create and move some elements in the page (like an admin panel).
the content of the inner page is separated and imported by an iframe.
so, when the user presses **Add Image** button the new component called view-image should be added inside a div element which has `id="content"`.

this is the logic I created:

```
@ViewChild('iframe') iframe: ElementRef;
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.loadIframe(this.iframe.nativeElement);
  }

  loadIframe(iframe: HTMLIFrameElement) {
    const doc = iframe.contentDocument;
    this.blocks$.subscribe(block=>{
      this.blocks$.subscribe(blocks=>{
      if(blocks != undefined && blocks.length > 0) {
        const component = this.vcRef.createComponent(ViewImageComponent);
        component.instance.bgColor = blocks[0].design.design.backgroundColor;
        component.instance.image = blocks[0].design.imageUrl;
        component.instance.imageAlt = blocks[0].design.imageAltText;
        component.instance.radius = blocks[0].design.design.borderRadius;
        component.instance.padding = blocks[0].design.design.padding;
        doc.querySelector('#content').appendChild(component.location.nativeElement);
      }
    })
  }
```

the block$ property contains the blocks which the user created stored inside ngrx store
this is my iframe:

```
<iframe id="pageFramenobanner" src="/assets/page-edit-content.html" width="100%" #iframe></iframe>
```

so the problem is that there is no element created inside iframe and no errors in the console
I'm sure the blocks$ property is not empty and the data is shown in the redux devtools

Comment: Hard to pinpoint an exact thing as there might be few faulty things here. Did you check whether component HTML isn't actually generated inside iframe but just without CSS you cannot see it? You can also try to debug step by step the code. Also, a reproducible example would be of much help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by calling the method `loadIframe` in the template instead of calling it inside `ngAfterViewInit` like this:

```
  <iframe id="pageFramenobanner" src="/assets/page-edit-content.html" width="100%" #iframe (load)="loadIframe(iframe)"></iframe>
```

so it seems that AfterViewInit hook doesn't wait for the iframe to load
hope that helps someone.